# How to get data from API before loading page

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I am trying to get data from an API to show on screen. I created a function and call it from widget build function. I also try to call it from constructor, but it will call that function in the end, so list empty error comes.

I want to call the API before screen load and store data in the list.

Comment: Please provide your code what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it by the below code:

First you have to Hit Api with a `onPressed` or `onTap` method within a Button like

```
onPressed: () {
  getNutritionDetails(context,"2");
  getDataFromMyApi(context);
},
```

Then make a function to make the code more clean and reader with any name, here i named the function as `getDataFromMyApi`

```
void getDataFromMyApi(BuildContext context) {
    //Getting data from API and store it in String or Model or List whatever you required.
    String myData;

    //and then pass the data to your second activity
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            MyStatefulWidget(myData), // Your Api response myData is Passing to Stateful Widget
      ),
    );
  }
```

and then i made a Stateful Widget where you want to pass the data and wants it to load data before it is opened and there you can have your data before the page loads in `myData` var.

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  String myData;

  MyStatefulWidget(this.myData, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
      child: Text(widget.myData),
    );
  }
}
```

### OR

**You Can Use Future Builder**

**Ques:** What does `Future Builder` do?

**Ans:** It calls the future function to wait for the result, and as soon as it produces the result it calls the builder function where we build the widget.

```
class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: downloadData(), // function where you call your api
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {  // AsyncSnapshot<Your object type>
      if( snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          return  Center(child: Text('Please wait its loading...'));
      }else{
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          else
            return Center(child: new Text('${snapshot.data}'));  // snapshot.data  :- get your object which is pass from your downloadData() function
      }
    },
  );
}
Future<String> downloadData()async{
  //   var response =  await http.get('https://getProjectList');    
  return Future.value("Data download successfully"); // return your response
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks , nice explanation..working like charm..

Comment: really glad to help. @MohammadArman

Comment: @Maz341 if to show loader with api data fetch in flutter

Comment: yeah you can use the same approach. When hitting the api set the value of isLoading to true (isLoading = true) and then after receiving response set isLoading = false;